# Send POST request using cURL to JWT python server - bad request

Tags: python, flask, curl, request, jwt

I'm using Python + Flask webserver which supports authentication and authorization from here: https://github.com/brunotatsuya/jwt-flask-rest-api.

I want to understand how JWT authorization / authentication works and I tried to send some simple requests using cURL and Python. However, **I'm getting a Bad Request every time**.

My cURL attempts:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth -d email=admin@admin.com -d password=bad_password

curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth --data '{"email":"admin@admin.com","password":"bad_password"}'

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth 
-d "{\"email\":\"admin@admin.com\",\"password\":\"bad_password\"}"

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth 
-d "email=admin@admin.com&password=bad_password"
```

And Python attempt:

```
import requests
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth'
x = requests.post(url, data="email=admin@admin.com&password=bad_password", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
print(x.text)
```

Can you explain me why?